# Hadamard Gap Theorem and Lacunary Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Does anyone know any good reference or even a simple proof for Hadamard Gap Theorem or even just the fact that a lacunary function diverges at 1 (I mean the limit not just the evaluation). In fact, I would just like to know an example of function with natural boundary on the unit open disk.

Comment: an easy example is $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0}z^{2^n}$ (at $w$ root of unity of order powers of $2$ clearly $|f(z)| \to \infty, z \to w$ and those are dense in the unit circle)

Comment: @Conrad Indeed I know of that example (it is a special case of what I have called lacunary functions in my question) but I couldn't prove that a lacunary function diverges at 1.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a lacunary function diverges at 1 as lacunary functions may converge (and even be infinitely differentiable in the real sense) on the boundary circle; the lacunary series have a singular point at $1$ (and everywhere on the boundary circle) but that is something quite different; there are various proofs - an easy one is in Krantz Greene p 286 https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-40-r